# Conditionally and efficiently locking on array of mutexes in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, locking, mutex

I have a simple work that is parallelized with OpenMP with very low scaling (2x speedup with 8 cores) due to too many locking:

```
struct MutexWithoutFalseSharing
{
    std::mutex mut;
    char padding[(64-sizeof(std::mutex))>0?(64-sizeof(std::mutex)):64];
};
MutexWithoutFalseSharing mutArr[256];

std::unordered_set<int> mapping[N];

// takes 4 milliseconds with omp, 8 milliseconds without omp 
// (8cores)
// (result is vector of std::pair of ints, 50k-100k elements)
#pragma omp parallel for
for(auto& r:result)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mutArr[r.first&255].mut);
    mapping[(r.first].insert(r.second);
}
```

what it does is simply taking an id (r.first) and another id (r.second) from same std::pair and inserting them into an array of sets.

The std::vector of std::pair (result) contains data like this pattern:

```
 r.first = {0,0,0,5,5,15,15,15,15,1000,1000,1270,4000,4000,4000,4000}
```

so that the locking algorithm picks same lock repeatedly, causing unnecessary extra latency. To evade the unnecessary extra locking, I'm thinking of this:

```
int lastId = -1000;
// assuming subResult is sub-set of original result (per-thread)
for(auto & r:subResult)
{
    if(lastId != r.first)
    {
        mutexArray[lastId].unlock();
        mutexArray[r.first].lock();
        lastId=r.first;
    }
    do_something_that_uses(r.first);
}
```

but this is not very exception-friendly nor undefined-behavior/deadlock-free. For example, second thread may run its own iteration before the first thread and unlock is wasted (because the first thread did not lock it).

Is there a sane/RAII-friendly way of doing this, without explicit locking? If there is none, how can I check if the selected lock (from array of locks) was locked before calling unlock?

Comment: In the last code `unlock` needs to be protected by a conditional so to about an out of bound and a last `unlock` after the loop is needed. AFAIK, there is nothing in the stard to implement that but you can do your own object to encapsulate such lock strategy. The thing is taking a lock already taken recently and not taken by another thread is generally very cheap (few ns). How expensive is your `do_something_that_uses` function (ie. how long does it last)? Note that a miss-predicted branch should take 10-15 cycle on mainstream x86 cpus. What about using an atomic data structure?

Comment: "Do something that uses" is about 10-20 cycles.

Comment: Ok, this is a pretty extreme case. Locking is generally cheap but not so much. A lock+unlock probably takes at least as much as 10-20 cycles on mainstream x86 processors: one cache line need to be locked and another one needs to be unlock and the new one will likely be stored in the L3 causing a pretty slow fetch. The acquire-release barrier caused by the lock/unlock also prevent some compiler/processor reordering optimizations. In your case, I think a better option is to partition the work so that each thread is ensured not to conflict with other (possibly using a sort).

Comment: As for the lock checking, this is possible with a `try_lock` but in your case this will cause a slow atomic operation on your critical path so this is not a good idea. While API designers could implement a `try_unlock` operation, there do not because this is rarely useful and the thread should know in which state locks are in most case (and otherwise they can use a local boolean variable). You can design your own spin locks using atomics. Spin locks are particularly good here regarding the granularity of the work to compute and the required low latency.